# Install PHP driver for MongoDB on MAMP

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, mamp

I'd like to install the PHP driver on MAMP 1.9.6 (OS X 10.5.8) and PHP 5.3

I did all the stuff said on http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center
But it still won't work.

If i try to connect it throws an error "Fatal Error: Class 'Mongo' not found"
But in PHPStorm the Mongo class is found and autocomplete works.
I added the extension in the php.ini

To install Mongo in terminal I wrote

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/pecl install mongo
```

And everything was installed properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this guide:

http://www.davidgolding.net/mongodb/installing-mongodb-on-mamp-1-9-5.html

The key part is grabbing the driver binary here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads

Copy the binary to the location stated in the guide, then make the change to your php.ini file.

Comment: there appears to be no mac driver there for download. was there one at the time you wrote this?

Comment: Yeah driver link is broken!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to do the following first:

```
sudo port install mongodb
```

I followed this link when installing and had no problems: [Apache, PHP and MongoDB on Mac OS X](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2010/01/02/apache-php-and-mongodb-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/)

Answer (score 1):

1. using the package manager of your choice (i.e. homebrew, port, apt-get, etc) install mongo
2. set up your MAMP environment to install additional extensions following this tutorial: http://blog.jellystyle.com/post/37099202581/installing-php-extensions-with-mamp
3. once your mamp is ready, run `sudo pecl install mongo`
4. restart mamp service
5. you should be able to run phpinfo() in a browser and find Mongo down there (and it should be the latest version)